# How to keep the values (dropping NAs) by groups?

Tags: r

My data has 3 proportion variables by geography and year. I am trying to aggregate this data by dropping the NAs and collating the values across 3 different variables by year and geography.

The example dataframe is as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(FIPS = c("01001", "01001", "01001","01001", "01001", "01001", "01003", "01003", "01003", "01003", "01003", "01003"),
                 Year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001),
                 prop1 = c(0.7, NA, NA, 0.5, NA, NA, 0.3, NA, NA, 0.5, NA, NA),
                 prop2 = c(NA, 0.3, NA, NA, 0.5, NA, NA, 0.3, NA, NA, 0.1, NA),
                 prop3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.4, NA, NA, 0.4))
```

I am guessing this can be done by aggregate or distinct command in R but not sure exactly how to proceed, as none of the way below gives me the dataframe I want.

```
df2 = aggregate(df,by = list(df$FIPS, df$Year), FUN = ???)

df2 <- df %>% distinct(FIPS, Year, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

The expected dataframe is as follows:

```
df2 <- data.frame(FIPS = c("01001", "01001",  "01003", "01003" ),
                  Year = c(2000,  2001,  2000,  2001),
                  prop1 = c(0.7,  0.5, 0.3, 0.5 ),
                  prop2 = c(0.3, 0.5,  0.3, 0.1),
                  prop3 = c(NA,  NA, 0.4, 0.4))
```

So basically, I want the code to search for the existing proportions (or NA if missing) in the 'prop' variables by Year and FIPS and create the new dataframe with unique FIPS and Year with the proportions collated. 
If anyone can point out the errors in what I am trying or give me another solution, it will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `dplyr` for this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(FIPS, Year) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(prop1:prop3), mean, na.rm = T) %>%
  replace(is.na(.), NA)
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   FIPS [?]
  FIPS   Year prop1 prop2 prop3
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 01001  2000   0.7   0.3  NA  
2 01001  2001   0.5   0.5  NA  
3 01003  2000   0.3   0.3   0.4
4 01003  2001   0.5   0.1   0.4
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R you can try,

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, list(df$FIPS, df$Year)), function(i) 
                                                     sapply(i, function(j) j[!is.na(j)][1])))

#           FIPS Year prop1 prop2 prop3
#01001.2000    1 2000   0.7   0.3    NA
#01003.2000    2 2000   0.3   0.3   0.4
#01001.2001    1 2001   0.5   0.5    NA
#01003.2001    2 2001   0.5   0.1   0.4
```

Comment: Hi @Sotos, Thanks! This take a little longer than the other answer, but solves my problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data.table` to achieve this-

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1L]), by =.(FIPS,Year)]
```

**Output-**

```
FIPS Year prop1 prop2 prop3
1: 01001 2000   0.7   0.3    NA
2: 01001 2001   0.5   0.5    NA
3: 01003 2000   0.3   0.3   0.4
4: 01003 2001   0.5   0.1   0.4
```

**Note**- This will be efficient, if you have large dataset

Comment: Thanks so much! Indeed this works and is as fast as dplyr solution!